# How to fill asp.net 2.0 gridview with ajax

Tags: ajax, gridview, asp.net-2.0

I have a search at the top of the page in ajax and I want to fill a asp.net 2.0 GridView with ajax.
How i can do this?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just put it in an ASP.Net Ajax UpdatePanel?

Comment: But Update panel is slow, what's your suggestion about speeding up update panel?